# Reuse step method in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, named-parameters

I am using common step method;

```
public void performAction(String actionText) {
//code to access actionText
}
```

Now I want to call this method in 2 ways. In the 1st case, I say;

```
I select action %action_text_taken_from_properties_string
```

Here I specify the annotation as

```
@When("I select action $actionText")
```

and inside performAction(), I use a custom processStepString() to get the actual value from a string properties file

Now in the 2nd case, I say;

```
I select action <action_text>
```

Here I use the Examples table to pass the value for action_text

So my annotation looks like

```
@When("I select action <action_text>")
```

But this requires me to have the signature as

```
public void performAction(@Named("action_text") String actionText)
```

My question is how do I use the same performAction() for both the cases ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using BDD driven approch, but you didnt specified what process you are using either Jbehave or Cucumber. I am assuming that you are using Jbehave. In Jbehave You can use @Alias Annotation like this

```
@When("a stock of symbol $symbol and a threshold of $threshold") // standalone
@Alias("a stock of <symbol> and a <threshold>") // examples table
public void aStock(@Named("symbol") String symbol, @Named("threshold") double threshold) {
// ...
}
```

you can refer [This Link](http://jbehave.org/reference/preview/aliases.html) for more info.

please let me know if it works .

Comment: Does any one know if there is Jbehave @Alias alike in Cucumber?